# Locking Mechanism on Tables

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, locking

We have a table TAB1 that's accessed by an Oracle process P1 (e.g. SID=123). The process demands a dynamic SQL delete followed by commit.

Process P1 initiated by SID=123 consists a lot of operations apart from this TAB1 related operation.

Scenario:

- SID=123 is active; P1 imposed a row exclusive lock on TAB1(got from querying locked_object view).
- another oracle process P2 is intiated by SID=124 (exactly same process as P1 but for different set of data inputs) just after sometime(say, 2-3 mins)P1 gets initiated.
- SID=124 is waiting till process P1 initiated by SID=123 is completed; P2 imposed a row exclusive lock on TAB1(got from querying locked_object view).

Question:

I think the same row level lock by P2 expects a 'can go-ahead' from row level lock by P1. 
Can we be able to MANUALLY OVERRIDE the locking imposed by process P1 on TAB1 (I hope it's possible), and release the lock once its operation on TAB1 is over? Will this help in reducing the long wait that P2 is now having on TAB1 till entire P1 is over?

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Please let me know if you need more information on this.

Comment: Your description is very low-level and focused on the current implementation and its problem. It doesn't give any information about what you really want to achieve. If you describe your task at a higher level and with more contextual information, you're more likely to get a helpful answer and a good solution.

Comment: @Codo: I hope the following description is fine? A table is getting locked due to simultaneous oracle processes and we would expect one process should wait only until the next process' operation on the table is active; not to wait till the first process' is getting completed.

Comment: What @codo was suggesting is that if you post what you are attempting to achieve someone may come up with a completely different solution that you hadn't considered.

Comment: @gallardolad: No, not at all. I'm rather thinking about something like: We have a long-running process that does some maintenance work in the database and - as part of that task - deletes expired offers from the OFFER table. It does not commit until the end of the work. Additionally, there's another process from an interactive user that updates several offers and normally takes less than a second. However, when the maintenance task is running, the interactive process gets blocked until the maintenance task is done. How can we avoid that?

Comment: @Codo: Okay! let me try. Please find the following description below- UPDATE BILL STATUS is a process thats operates on BILL STATUS table which has a commit at the end of the process. Its now been called by two different CUSTOMERS(which is a new scneario). This process not only insert/update/delete BILL STATUS table but also does similar operations various other tables. When more than one CUSTOMERS submits this process we get such behaviour. Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: Are the two processes affecting the same row?  I would expect that the set of rows that would be related to one customer would be completely distinct from the set of rows that would be related to another customer so I wouldn't expect the two sessions to try to modify the same row.  The only reason that one session doing DML would block another session doing DML is if both sessions are trying to modify the same row.  If two sessions are trying to modify the same row, you can't manually unlock the row. But generally you can architect the process to avoid the conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Locks are released on **transaction** boundary, not on **process** boundary.

In short, if you want P1 to immediately release the lock, P1 has to end the current transcation with an explicit commit or rollback just after the delete operation.

Of course ending the transaction would also commit/rollback other operations that were executed in the same session after the previous commit/rollback. If this is a problem, you have to rethink the business logic.

Wait, you wrote "dynamic SQL delete followed by commit"... if you mean "immediately followed" then the row exclusive lock is already immediately released.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually 'avoided the scenario' which means 'this answer is not the solution' to the question being asked.
What I've did to avoid the scenario:

1. Added one more column to TAB1 to put a unique identification number for each process.
2. Used this column to delete only the rows corresponding to that particular process.     *This, I believe has avoided the processes P1 and P2 waiting for the same row.*

Thanks to @Codo, @a_horse_with_no_name, @Ben, @Justin Cave and @colemar for all your help in trying to prettify the question context-wise and for your support.

@Justin Cave: I've been thinking the same solution as proposed by you, but if I would've seen this yesterday, I wouldn't have to waste time till now. Anyways, thanks a lot for your support.